# Ответ на запрос к серверу обрабатывается не той функцией

Tags: c++, qt, веб-программирование, qt5, qnetworkrequest

Есть функция, которая производит аутентификацию

```
void WebConnector::authRequest() {
    QNetworkRequest *request = new QNetworkRequest(auth);
    QUrlQuery *params = new QUrlQuery();
    params->addQueryItem("username", LOGIN);
    params->addQueryItem("password", PASSWORD);
    request->setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request->setRawHeader("username:" LOGIN, "password:" PASSWORD);
    //Присоединение завершения запроса к функции postAuth
    QObject::connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), SLOT(postAuth(QNetworkReply*)));
    manager->post(*request, params->toString().toUtf8());
}
```

Вот функция, которая принимает ответ

```
void WebConnector::postAuth(QNetworkReply *rep) {
    QByteArray bts = rep->readAll();
    QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(bts);
    QJsonObject root = document.object();
    QJsonValue val = root.find("token").value();
    if(val.isArray()) {
        QJsonArray array = val.toArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < array.count(); i++) {
            QJsonObject subtree = array.at(i).toObject();

        }
    }
    QString str(bts);
    qDebug() << str;
    this->token = val.toString();
    this->getMainUserPosts();
}
```

Так же есть функция, которая делает другой запрос к серверу

```
void WebConnector::getMainUserPosts() {
    QNetworkRequest *requestEtion = new QNetworkRequest(userPosts);
    requestEtion->setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www/form-urlencoded");
    requestEtion->setRawHeader("Authorization", "Bearer Token");
    manager->get(*requestEtion);
    QObject::connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), SLOT(getMainUserPostsRequest(QNetworkReply*)));
}
```

Функция которая должна обработать ответ, но при отладке переменная borrow пустая

```
void WebConnector::getMainUserPostsRequest(QNetworkReply *reply) {
  QByteArray borrow = reply->readAll();
  qDebug() << QString(borrow);
}
```

Ответ приходит в postAuth, почему так?

Comment: Вы в функции `WebConnector::authRequest()` привязываете к сигналу `finished(QNetworkReply*)` слот `postAuth(QNetworkReply*)`, а потом к этому же сигналу в функции `WebConnector::getMainUserPosts()` привязываете слот `getMainUserPostsRequest(QNetworkReply*)`.  Оба слота должны выполнять чтение из `QNetworkReply*`. Возможно, дело в том, что `postAuth` вызывается раньше, и когда срабатывает `getMainUserPostsRequest`, то ей уже просто нечего читать?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, функция `WebConnector::authRequest()` как раз должна вызываться перед `WebConnector::getMainUserPosts()`, она получает токен, который надо передать в `WebConnector::getMainUserPosts()`. Как лучше реализовать это, чтобы разные функции обрабатывали разные ответы?

Comment: С ходу не приходит в голову ничего лучшего, чем сделать отдельную функцию, которая будет читать ответ, анализировать, что за ответ получен, и вызывать соответствующий обработчик. Проблема в том ,что при чтении полученного сообщения оно удаляется из буфера QNetworkReply и остается только там, куда Вы его прочитали. Так что прочитать можно только один раз.